# how to fix textures being mixed with colours?

Tags: javascript, webgl, fragment-shader

Current Problem

[image: Current problem]

Intended Wall texture

[image: Intended Wall texture]

The wall is not drawn with the desired texture. Random colors are being mixed with the wall texture on the cylinder. The rest of the objects don't need a texture. The program is run on a localhost and the image is definitely being loaded. Here is my code for the building. How can I fix the texture problem?
The script library gl-matrix-mi.js is loaded as well. There are 2 buttons and 2 sliders created in the html file which calls initDemo().

```
var mat4 = glMatrix.mat4;
var segments = 64,m_zoom=5,zoomValue=5;
var xRotateNeg = 1,m_XAngle=0,xRotSpeed=5;
var groundVertices = null;
var cylVertices=[];
var points = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0];
var coneVertices=[];
var indices=[];
var positionAttribLocation = null;
var colorAttribLocation = null;
var gl = null;
var program = null;
var theVertexBufferObject = null;
var matWorldUniformLocation =null;
var matViewUniformLocation  =null;
var matProjectionUniformLocation    =null;
var worldMatrix         = null;
var viewMatrix          = null;
var projectionMatrix    = null;
var canvas = null;
var myElement= null;
var wallTexture = null;

var vertexShaderText =
[
'precision mediump float;',
'',
'attribute vec3 vertPosition;',
'attribute vec3 vertColor;',
'attribute vec2 vertTexCoord;',
'varying vec2 fragTexCoord;',
'varying vec3 fragColor;',
'uniform mat4 mWorld;',
'uniform mat4 mView;',
'uniform mat4 mProjection;',
'',
'void main()',
'{',
'   fragColor = vertColor;',
'   fragTexCoord = vertTexCoord;',
'   gl_Position = mProjection * mView * mWorld * vec4(vertPosition, 1.0);',
'}'
].join('\n');

var fragmentShaderText =
[
'precision mediump float;',
'',
'varying vec3 fragColor;',
'void main()',
'{',
'   gl_FragColor = vec4(fragColor, 1.0);',
'}'
].join('\n');

var fragTexShaderText =
[
'precision mediump float;',
'',
'varying vec2 fragTexCoord;',
'uniform sampler2D sampler;',
'void main()',
'{',
'   gl_FragColor = texture2D(sampler,fragTexCoord);',
'}'
].join('\n');

var initDemo = function () {
    console.log('This is working');

    canvas = document.getElementById('game-surface');
    gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');

    if (!gl) {
        console.log('WebGL not supported, falling back on experimental-webgl');
        gl = canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl');
    }
    if (!gl) {
        alert('Your browser does not support WebGL');
    }

    clear();
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    //
    //Create Shaders
    //
    var vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    var fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    var fragmentTexShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    gl.shaderSource(vertexShader,vertexShaderText);
    gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader,fragmentShaderText);
    gl.shaderSource(fragmentTexShader,fragTexShaderText);

    gl.compileShader(vertexShader);

    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader,gl.COMPILE_STATUS)){
        console.error('ERROR compiling vertex shader!', gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader));
        return;
    }

    gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);

    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(fragmentShader,gl.COMPILE_STATUS)){
        console.error('ERROR compiling fragment shader!', gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader));
        return;
    }

    gl.compileShader(fragmentTexShader);

    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(fragmentTexShader,gl.COMPILE_STATUS)){
        console.error('ERROR compiling fragment tex shader!', gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentTexShader));
        return;
    }
    //
    //  set Listeners
    //
    document.getElementById("btnStopStart").addEventListener("click", f_StopStart); 
    document.getElementById("btnRedirect").addEventListener("click", f_ChangeDirection);
    document.getElementById("sldRotation").addEventListener("change", f_AdjustRotSpeed);
    document.getElementById("sldZoom").addEventListener("change", f_AdjustZoom);
    xRotSpeed   =document.getElementById("sldRotation").value;
    m_zoom      =document.getElementById("sldZoom").value;
    //
    //  Attach Shaders
    //
    program = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(program,vertexShader);
    gl.attachShader(program,fragmentShader);

    gl.linkProgram(program);
    if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program,gl.LINK_STATUS)){
        console.error('ERROR linking program!', gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
        return;
    }

    //
    //Set vertices
    //
    var y=2, k=0, radius=1; //The origin
    var red=0.5,green=0.4,blue=0.4;
    var u=0;
    for (i =0;i<=(segments);i++){
        u = i / (360/segments*2.13);
        x = radius*Math.cos(2*Math.PI*u);
        z = radius*Math.sin(2*Math.PI*u);

        if (k>7){k=0};
        //Bottom cylinder
        cylVertices.push( x, 0, z, points[k] , points[k+1]);
        k+=2;
        //Top cylinder
        cylVertices.push( x, y, z, points[k] , points[k+1]);
        k+=2;
        //Cone Bottom vertices
        coneVertices.push(x, y, z);
        coneVertices.push(red-0.2,green-0.2,blue-0.2);
        //Cone Top vertices
        coneVertices.push(0, y+2, 0);
        coneVertices.push(red-0.2,green-0.2,blue-0.2);
    }

    groundVertices =
    [   //T1 X,Y,Z          R  ,G ,B
        -4.0,   -0.01,  4.0,    0.1,0.8,0.1,
        -4.0,   -0.01,  -4.0,   0.1,0.8,0.1,
        4.0,    -0.01,  -4.0,   0.1,0.8,0.1,
        //T2
        4.0,    -0.01,  4.0,    0.1,0.8,0.1,
        -4.0,   -0.01,  4.0,    0.1,0.8,0.1,
        4.0,    -0.01,  -4.0,   0.1,0.8,0.1
    ];
    cylArray    = new Float32Array(cylVertices); //sidearray
    coneArray   = new Float32Array(coneVertices); //cone side array


    matWorldUniformLocation =gl.getUniformLocation(program,'mWorld');
    matViewUniformLocation  =gl.getUniformLocation(program,'mView');
    matProjectionUniformLocation=gl.getUniformLocation(program,'mProjection');

    worldMatrix         = new Float32Array(16);
    viewMatrix          = new Float32Array(16);
    projectionMatrix    = new Float32Array(16);

    xRotationMatrix = new Float32Array(16);
    gl.useProgram(program);
    var identityMatrix = new Float32Array(16);
    mat4.identity(identityMatrix);
    //
    //------MAIN RENDER LOOP-------
    //
    var angle = 0;
    var loop = function (){
        setCamera();
        angle = performance.now() / 1000 / 6 * 2 * Math.PI;
        mat4.rotate(xRotationMatrix,identityMatrix, angle * (m_XAngle*0.1) * xRotateNeg, [0,1,0]);//x rotation
        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(matWorldUniformLocation, gl.FALSE, xRotationMatrix);

        clear();

        theVertexBufferObject = gl.createBuffer();
        colorBufferObject = gl.createBuffer();

        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttribLocation);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(colorAttribLocation);

        drawCone();
        drawGround();

        gl.detachShader(program,fragmentShader);
        gl.attachShader(program,fragmentTexShader);

        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, wallTexture);
        gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
        drawCylSide();

        gl.detachShader(program,fragmentTexShader);
        gl.attachShader(program,fragmentShader);

        requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    };
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
};
//
// --------------------functions--------------------
//
//  Draw Cylinder
function drawCylSide(){
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,theVertexBufferObject);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(cylArray),gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    setPointer(5);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttribLocation);

    var texCoordAttribLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program,'vertTexCoord');
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(
        texCoordAttribLocation,             //Attribute location
        2,                                  //Number of vertix elements
        gl.FLOAT,                           //Type of elements
        gl.FALSE,                           //Normalised
        5 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, //Size of individual vertex
        3 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, //Offset
    );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(texCoordAttribLocation);
    wallTexture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, wallTexture);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S,gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T,gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,gl.LINEAR);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,gl.LINEAR);
    gl.texImage2D(
        gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA,
        gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        document.getElementById('wall-img')
    );
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);

    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP,0, segments);
};
//
// Draw Cone
//
function drawCone(){
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,theVertexBufferObject);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(coneArray),gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    setPointer(6);
    setColorPointer();
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(colorAttribLocation);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP,0, segments);
};
//
//  Draw Floor
//
function drawGround(){
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,theVertexBufferObject);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(groundVertices),gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    setPointer(6);

    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 3, 3);
};
//
//  Pointers
//
function setPointer(n){
    positionAttribLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program,'vertPosition');
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(
        positionAttribLocation,             //Attribute location
        3,                                  //Number of vertix elements
        gl.FLOAT,                           //Type of elements
        gl.FALSE,                           //Normalised
        n * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, //Size of individual vertex
        0                                   //Offset
    );
};
function setColorPointer(){
    colorAttribLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program,'vertColor');
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(
        colorAttribLocation,                //Attribute location
        3,                                  //Number of vertix elements
        gl.FLOAT,                           //Type of elements
        gl.FALSE,                           //Normalised
        6 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, //Size of individual vertex
        3 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, //Offset
    );
};
function clear(){
    gl.clearColor(0.75, 0.85, 0.8, 1.0);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
};
function setCamera(){
    mat4.identity(worldMatrix);
    mat4.lookAt(viewMatrix,[0,1,(-1*m_zoom)],[0,0,0],[0,10,0]);
    mat4.perspective(projectionMatrix,glMatrix.glMatrix.toRadian(45),canvas.width/canvas.height,0.1,1000.0);

    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(matWorldUniformLocation,gl.FALSE,worldMatrix);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(matViewUniformLocation,gl.FALSE,viewMatrix);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(matProjectionUniformLocation,gl.FALSE,projectionMatrix);    
};
function f_StopStart(){
    if (m_XAngle!=0) {m_XAngle=0}
    else{m_XAngle=document.getElementById("sldRotation").value;};
};
function f_ChangeDirection(){
    xRotateNeg= xRotateNeg*-1;
};
function f_AdjustRotSpeed(){
    xRotSpeed=document.getElementById("sldRotation").value;
    m_XAngle=xRotSpeed;
};
function f_AdjustZoom(){
    zoomValue=document.getElementById("sldZoom").value;
    m_zoom=zoomValue;
};
```

The goal would be for only the wall (cylinder) to have texture.

Answer (score 0):

After detaching/attaching shader object a program needs to be re-linked (with `linkProgram` call). However, a better way would be to create two separate program object with the same vertex shader and different fragment shaders, and switch them with `useProgram` (since it does require shaders to regenerate shader binaries several times in a frame).

Answer (score 0):

As Kirill pointed out if you leave your code the same you'd need to call `gl.linkProgram` after detaching and attaching new shaders but that effectively makes a new program. All your uniform locations will become invalid and you'll need to look up the locations again. It's not common to do things that way.

It's far [more common to create multiple programs at init time and use them at render time](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-drawing-multiple-things.html)

Uniforms also are not shared across programs. You need to look up attribute and uniform locations for each program even if they have the same names.

You might find [these tutorials](https://webglfundamentals.org) useful.